# another excel offset question

Tags: excel, offset

what will this do:??

```
=SUM(OFFSET(E6,0,0,$C$1,1))
```

here's the syntax of offset:

```
OFFSET(reference,rows,cols,height,width)
```

how can you put a height as being $C$1 ? what does this do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will use the number in the cell `C1` as the height.

NB: *The `$` make this an absolute reference, ie when you copy the formulate to another field (eg with drag and drop, or that magic resize) it will keep referring to `C1` instead of being changed to a field relative to the new location of the formula.*

Answer (score 3):

This will use the number in the cell `$C$1` as the height.

Comment: The dollars ($) make an cell address absolute so when the formula is copied that portion of the cell address does not change, so $C$1 is a reference to C1 where both the column and row will not change when copied.